# Solving for end_date using yearfrac() formula in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I'm not sure this is possible, but I am looking for a formula that would allow me to back solve for the end date of a YEARFRAC() formula, using a start_date and YEARFRAC() end value (fine to use the default US 30/360 basis).

For example, using the input YEARFRAC(13-Sep-2023,01-Dec-2033) produces the value 10.21666667.  Using the same start_date, I would like to solve for the end date that would make YEARFRAC() equal to 10.000 exactly.

Is this possible using YEARFRAC(), or am I going about things the wrong way?

Thanks

Comment: Umm wouldn't that just be `13-sep-2033` because you are just adding 10 years? `="13-sep-2023"+date(10,0,0)`